# Is $A$ a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory

Consider
$$A=a^2+2ab^2+b^4-4bc-4b^3,$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\neq0$ such that $b|a$ and $b|c$, so $b|A$.

Now I want to know that **Is $A$ a perfect square?**

Comment: Yes. Consider $a=3, b=1, c=2$.

Comment: How about in general case?

Comment: What is a "general case"?

Comment: I meant that for every a,b,c, does there exist any t such that $A=t^2$?

Comment: Your question is "Can $A$ be a perfect square", for which the answer is yes. Your "general case" is whether $A$ is always a perfect square, for which you should be able to verify after plugging in a few different values of $a,b,c$.

Comment: you right, I edited it

Answer (score 3):

In general, A is obviously not a perfect square. A counterexample is when a = 3, b=1 and c=1 in which case A = 8. However, there are many values of a, b, and c where A is a perfect square. One special case is when b = 1. If b = 1, and you let a + 1 be the hypotenuse of a right triangle whose sides are natural numbers and let $c = \frac{E^{2}}{4}-1$, where E is an even leg of the right triangle, then you can find infinitely many solutions to meet the conditions of your equation. For example, take the Pythagorean triple 5, 4, 3.

a + 1 = 5 which means a = 4
b = 1
$c = \frac{4^{2}}{4}-1=3$

You can view a list of Pythagorean triples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple).

Comment: would you give any counter exam except $b=1$?

Comment: Yes, let a = 100, b = 2 and c = 5. Counterexamples are easy to find.

Comment: @ Math777, $2 \not | 5$.(it should have the condition $b|c$)

Comment: True. Let a = 100, b = 2 and c = 6, then A = 10226.

Answer (score 1):

No, $A$ is not a perfect square for such $a,b,c$ values. As a counterexample, take $a=b=c=1$, for which $A=-4$.

---

**EDIT:** The answer below corresponds to the original question "*Can $A$ be a perfect square?*".

Yes, it can be 0. Let $a=bn$ and $c=bm$. Then:
$$\begin{align}
A&=a^2+2ab^2+b^4-4bc-4b^3\\
&=b^2n^2+2b^3n+b^4-4b^2m-4b^3\\
&=b^2 \big((n+b)^2-4(m+b)\big)
\end{align}$$
So any values that make $(n+b)^2-4(m+b)$ a square are valid ones. So, for instance, any $n=-b$ and $m=-b$ are enough, but you can find many others.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I edited my question.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi See the edit